# PHP snippet not working

Tags: php

I'm really new to php and am having trouble debugging the following snippet.

```
<?php
$hintMaintain = <<< EOT
    <hr />
    <div id="user_hint"> ABC DE <span class="status_strtolower($account['status_value'])">ucfirst($account['status_value'])</span>FGH</div>

    <div style="margin: 0px 74px 0px 74px; text-align: center; height: 66px; width:66px; background: url('img/strtolower($maintain)hint.png') no-repeat;">
        <span style="line-height: 66px; font-size: 36px; color: black;">$countdown</span>
    </div>
EOT;

eval("\$hintMaintain = \"$hintMaintain\";");
?>
<!-- SOME HTML -->

<?php echo $hintMaintain; ?>
```

This shows a server error. I haven't been able to work this out.

Help?
Thanks.

Comment: Big huge stinkin santax error. How did you miss it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$hintMaintain = '<hr />
<div id="user_hint">
    <p> ABC DE 
         <span class="status_'.strtolower($account['status_value']).'">'.ucfirst($account['status_value']).'</span>
    FGH</p>
</div>

<div style="margin: 0px 74px 0px 74px; text-align: center; height: 66px; width:66px; background: url(\'img/'.strtolower($maintain).'hint.png\') no-repeat;">
    <span style="line-height: 66px; font-size: 36px; color: black;">'.$countdown.'</span>
</div>';
?>
<!-- SOME HTML -->
<?php echo $hintMaintain; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <hr />
 <div id="user_hint"> ABC DE 
<span class="status_strtolower(<? =$account['status_value']); ?>">
<? =ucfirst($account['status_value']);?>
</span>FGH</div>
<div style="margin: 0px 74px 0px 74px; text-align: center; height: 66px; width:66px; background: url('img/<?=strtolower($maintain);?>hint.png') no-repeat;">
    <span style="line-height: 66px; font-size: 36px; color: black;"><?=$countdown/></span>
</div>
```

---

```
<? =$something; ?>
```

^^^ will output this something.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

You are trying to execute HTML as PHP

Look at the phpdocs on eval http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

The first argument must be valid PHP statements.

I think you are trying to cache the content and display it after, look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Comment: So, adding an 'echo' would work? I am a little confused about this. Thanks.